# Paradox? What's wrong with this thinking?

Tags: infinite-product, fake-proofs, paradoxes

Let $x = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \cdots$

Thus, $x = 2x \Rightarrow x = 0$

So, $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times \cdots = 0$

---

This clearly doesn't make any sense.
What's wrong then?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $x= 2 \times 2 \times \ldots$ makes no sense.

Comment: Can't we define $x$ as an infinite product? Can we do so as an infinite sum?

Comment: Only if it converges. Defining $x = 1 + 1 + \cdots$, thus $1 + x = 1 + 1 + \cdots = x$, thus $1 = 0$ is equally meaningless.

Comment: What you wrote is $x = \infty$ so $2x = \infty$, and $2x = x \implies x = 0 \iff \infty = 0$.

Comment: In any case, also if we define the number $x$ in a correct way, e.g. $x=2+3$, we cannot assert that is is "the same" $x$ of the *equation* $x = 2x$.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen continued fractions and nested roots and I knew there had to be some restriction on doing that, but I couldn't work it out. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: If you're going to allow $x$ to represent an infinite quantity, then the equation $x=2x$ is also satisfied by $x=\infty$, so no contradiction here.

Comment: "*Let $x=2\times 2\times\dots$ makes no sense*"  I would argue that it still does make sense as $x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n 2$.  The difficulty here is that what you are trying to do is essentially $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n 2-\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\prod\limits_{j=1}^m 2$ which is [indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) of the form $\infty-\infty$.  Just like how $\frac{\infty}{\infty},\frac{0}{0},1^\infty$ have no consistent value to assign to them, so too does $\infty-\infty$ depend on context.

Comment: The error is in assuming that $2x=x\implies x=0$.  Although true for finite real numbers, this is not necessarily true for infinite numbers as is the case here for your $x$.

Comment: Twist the $0$ and lay it down. Then $2\times\infty=\infty$.

Comment: Truly enriching comments. Thank you everyone, now I do understand where the mistake was!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to have products of an infinite number of factors in a hyperreal number system.  However, the infinite number, say $H$, is a specific one not equal to $H+1$.  Therefore your $x=\prod_{i=1}^H 2$ is *not* equal to $2x=\prod_{i=1}^{H+1}2$ and the paradox disappears.